# List 8 latest products on homepage - Magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I know this question gets asked quite a bit and seems straight forward but I can't seem to find a post which states an answer that works.

There a few with solutions on how to list products marked with a 'new from' date in the backend and there are solutions which list the latest products from a specific category but I just need the 8 most recently added products to the catalog full stop.

Currently I am manually adding the products to a 'latest products' category with an ID of 116

and have this in the content of my home page CMS page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="116" template="catalog/product/list-latest.phtml"}}
```

Then in the list-latest.phtml template file, I have some code to get the collection:

```
    <?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()->setPageSize(10);
    $_productCollection->clear(); //this will unset the loaded items.
    $_productCollection->getSelect()->limit(10); //set a new limit
    $_productCollection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER); //reset the order
    $_productCollection->getSelect()->order('cat_index_position asc');//force order by position in category
    $_productCollection->load();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
```

And then it loops through the collection and works fine but I need a way to get the latest products from ALL categories and automatically put the latest 8 products on the homepage.

Is there a way to alter this code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

Place below code in you home page via admin login cms->select your home page->
design->Layout Update XML

```html
 <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
             <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
             <action method="setProductsCount"><count>8</count></action>
        </block>
```

The above code will show you new product with four columns per row and total 8 product limit.

Let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 0):

I did this using a widget. Create a widget with:

- type:Catalog new products list
- Display On: where you want it
- In the Widget Options tab: Display Type: all products (you can select New Products but then you have to mark products as new rather than the latest you added)

There are other options that are self-explanatory.

You will probably have to theme your widget but it shouldn't be too different to a normal product displays.